# php/js/ajax search box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, livesearch

I have a Google style searchbox.  However, unlike with Google I don't want page to change when user selects from suggestions as there are other fields.  Instead, I am using javascript to set a value in the email field once a user selects it.  My problem is all the suggestions remain, filling up screen.

javascript:

```
function setEmail(address) {
//alert(address);
var email = '<input type="email" name="to" value="\''+address+'\'">';
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = email;
document.getElementById('suggestions').innerHTML = "";
}
```

links returned by ajax:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setEmail('.$address.');">Name</a>
```

html:

Edited to show answer below:

```
<input id="box" type="email" name="to" onkeyup="showSuggestions(this.value)">
```

Edit 2: To make the suggestions disappear after selection, I set the suggestion box to "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the input an ID. like this:

```
<input id="emailField" type="email" name="to" onkeyup="showEmail(this.value)">
```

And change this:

```
document.getElementById('emailbox').innerHTML = email;
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById('emailField').value = email;
```